# Difference between "fill" and "expand" options for tkinter pack method

Tags: python, tkinter

What's the difference between the "`fill`" and "`expand`" options for Tkinter's `pack` method?

I have actually looked up about it everywhere, and I am unable to find the satisfactory answer. I found the following:

> `fill` option: it determines whether to use up more space or keep
> "one's own" dimensions.
>
> `expand` option: it deals with the expansion of parent widget.

The problem is that these two sound more or less the same. I even tried out a few examples by toggling between the 4 values of `fill` and 2 values of `expand` but received more or less the same output in 2 or 3 cases, because of which I have this query.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112024617/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm):

> The **fill** option tells the manager that the widget wants fill the entire space assigned to it. The value controls how to fill the space; **BOTH** means that the widget should expand both horizontally and vertically, **X** means that it should expand only horizontally, and **Y** means that it should expand only vertically.
>
> The **expand** option tells the manager to assign additional space to the widget box. If the parent widget is made larger than necessary to hold all packed widgets, any exceeding space will be distributed among all widgets that have the **expand** option set to a non-zero value.

So `fill` tells the widget to grow to as much space is available for it in the direction specified, `expand` tells the master to take any space that is not assigned to any widget and distribute it to all widgets that have a non-zero `expand` value.

The difference becomes clear when running this example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+200+200')

tk.Label(root, text='Label', bg='green').pack(expand=1, fill=tk.Y)
tk.Label(root, text='Label2', bg='red').pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

You can see that the label with `expand=1` gets assigned as much space as available for it, but only occupies it in the direction specified, Y.
The label with `fill=tk.BOTH` expands in both directions, but has less space available.

[image: Expand vs Fill]

Comment: Oh sorry, from the way you described it I assumed it came from somewhere else. To get some more feeling for the two options, you can play around with the options from the example a bit, remove the `expand` from label1, set  `expand` to 1 for both, try `fill=tk.X`...  The background color really shows which part of the master (which is root in this case) the widgets use.

Comment: Yeah I tried them. And what I came to assume is that python by default assigns the entire horizontal space to a widget. So, even if `expand = 0` but `fill = X` the widget fills the entire horizontal screen space. However,  if `expand = 0` but `fill = Y` is written, then the widget size remains the same. Is it correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct for widgets packed with `side=TOP` (default) and `BOTTOM`. For `side=LEFT` and `RIGHT`, the widget is automatically expanded in the `Y` direction. You can see by setting `fill=BOTH` for both and `side=LEFT` for one of them.

Comment: Awesome! Tried it for `side=LEFT` & `side=RIGHT` and got the result which you have mentioned. Surely, this cleared all the doubts regarding the `fill` and `expand` options. Thanks again!

Answer (score 125):

I'm done with trial and error. Here is an overview:

[image: fill and side combinations with expand = False]
[image: fill and side combinations with expand = True]

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry()

for e, expand in enumerate([False, True]):
    for f, fill in enumerate([None, tk.X, tk.Y, tk.BOTH]):
        for s, side in enumerate([tk.TOP, tk.LEFT, tk.BOTTOM, tk.RIGHT]):
            position = '+{}+{}'.format(s * 205 + 100 + e * 820, f * 235 + 100)
            win = tk.Toplevel(root)
            win.geometry('200x200'+position)
            text = str("side='{}'\nfill='{}'\nexpand={}".format(side, fill, str(expand)))
            tk.Label(win, text=text, bg=['#FF5555', '#55FF55'][e]).pack(side=side, fill=fill, expand=expand)
                
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a nice visual guide! Although I don't exactly agree with `expand=True overrules side='...'`. It might seem that way when you have only one widget such as in your example, but it certainly isn't true when you have more than one.

Comment: My bad, indeed I only looked at windows with a single widget. I changed it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the best answer I've found about it.

Comment: Well that was a quality answer

Comment: @Ronald This answer is so freakin good!! Is it just simple with the underlying code and just works. THANK YOU! You are someone who keeps the world together and running and just making it a better place <3

Answer (score 18):

I'm also a man who struggled to understand how those options work together.

Thankfully, finally got clear understanding with Ronald's visual explanation.

So I made some program to simulate how pack works.
https://github.com/thom-jp/tkinter_pack_simulator

Here is the image of running program:

[image: Here is the image of running program]