# Tkinter : I don't understand how the grid works (trying to create equally sized columns)

Tags: python, tkinter, center

My goal is to create 3 equally sized columns in tkinter and then be able to fill them with whatever I want.
What I'm trying to do is similar to the grid system in bootstrap but in tkinter adding something in a column makes the column bigger.

My question is then, how can you create fix sized columns ?

Thanks !

the code that creates columns that are not equal :

```
class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background = "black")

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Weather", fg = "white", bg="green", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0, sticky = 'new')

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Time", fg = "white", bg="blue", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 0, sticky = 'nwe')

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Test", fg = "white", bg="red", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 2, pady = 0, sticky = 'nwe')

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "News", fg = "white", bg="black", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 0, pady = 10, sticky = 'sw')
```

Comment: `sticky` cannot have `center` as an option. It must be a string containing n, e, s, and/or w. The grid manager will resize things bases on some parameters you can manage. I have a few post on this matter I am looking for one now for reference. Here are 2 post on the topic: [Some elementary tkinter questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070459/some-elementary-tkinter-questions/46078655#46078655) and [Find position of another anchor than the anchor already used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749781/find-position-of-another-anchor-than-the-anchor-already-used/50750928#50750928)

Comment: it would help if you reduced this down to a [mcve]. For example, the `Main` class seems unrelated to the question being asked.

Comment: well it is complete and verifiable, and from my point of view, the main class is necessary to be on the same page, maybe for some reason running tkinter outside from an object doesn't give the same result, but the only import part is the mainpage class

Comment: They will not have the same size. You have one of your widgets off to the 2nd column so this will be part of your size difference.

Comment: Yes, it's complete and verifiable, but not _minimal_.

Comment: @Shraneid What do you expect the layout to look like exactly?

Comment: My bad, I thought this would help as you can just copy paste to run the whole thing

Comment: I would expect it to have 3 columns of equal width but for some reason one is bigger

Comment: You added another widget. that will change my answer.

Comment: So after clearing up what it is you are trying to do I can tell you that adding a weight does not mean all columns will be exactly the same size. It Just means that each column will expand evenly to fill the available space.

Comment: If what you want are three evenly sized columns, please edit your question to remove almost everything you've written and start over by saying that you want three equally sized columns.

Comment: Add `Label(..., width=32`) to get equal sized Labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grid` has an option specifically for equally sized columns and rows: `uniform`. It takes any string as a value, and all columns with the same value will be the same size.

In your case it would look like this:

```
self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1, uniform="x")
self.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1, uniform="x")
self.columnconfigure(2, weight = 1, uniform="x")
```

Comment: What I would like is three equally sized columns and then being able to fill them how I want to

Comment: @Shraneid: if you want equally sized columns, you should have asked how to create three equally sized columns.

Comment: (sorry for the ncenter I know it doesn't work, it was just a test but for some reason it's not saving the edits as I'm trying to put sticky="new" back)

Comment: Oh that is cool. I did not know that was an option for columnconfig! I am sure I can use that somewhere in my application :D

Comment: Do you have a link to a well made documentation about tkinter ?

Comment: @Mike - SMT, just saw in [Tcl documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grid.htm) that you can also supply columnconfigure with a list of indexes if you want: `self.columnconfigure([0,1,2], weight=1)`, which also is cool if you are making arrays of widgets.