# Python-Tkinter Place button on left of frame

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I place the QUIT button in below code to the extreme right of the Frame?
I tried several things like:

> padx

and

> self.pack(side="top", anchor="e")

but after trying some 15 times both buttons are coming close to each other. Maybe Some help from anyone would be really appreciated. I need one button on extreme  right and other on extreme  left

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.master.title("Log Parser")
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.Run_Main = tk.Button(self)
        self.Run_Main["text"] = "Browse.."
        # self.Run_Main["fg"] = "blue"
        self.Run_Main["command"] = self.Sayhello
        self.Run_Main.pack(side='left')
        self.Label = tk.Label(self)
        self.Label["text"] = 'Processing...'
        self.progressbar = Progressbar(mode="indeterminate", maximum=20)
        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "Quit!"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit
        self.QUIT.pack(anchor='e')
        self.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

    def Sayhello(self):
       print("Hello")

# scroll text inside application frame
class scrollTxtArea:
    def __init__(self, root):
        frame = tk.Frame(root)
        frame.pack()
        self.textPad(frame)
        return

    def textPad(self, frame):
        # add a frame and put a text area into it
        textPad = tk.Frame(frame)
        self.text = tk.Text(textPad, height=18, width=60)
        self.text.config()
        # add a vertical scroll bar to the text area
        scroll = tk.Scrollbar(textPad)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set,background="black", foreground="green")
        # pack everything
        self.text.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=2)
        scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        textPad.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        return

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.option_add('*font', ('verdana', 9, 'bold'))
app = Application(master=root)
scrollFrame = scrollTxtArea(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems here.

First, you're using the wrong geometry manager.  The pack geometry manager, as the name implies, packs the widgets as close together as possible.  That's not what you want. The grid geometry manager lets you put the widgets into a table-like layout with rows and columns.  If you put the Browse button into the first column and the Quit button into the last column, you'll be a step closer.

Second, your `Application` window contains three child widgets and you're only putting two of them into a geometry manager.  How that is going to mess you up I don't even want to think about.  So I put the label into column 1, the Quit button into column 2, and the Browse button into column 0.  The Quit button I gave a "sticky" value of "e" so it will be attached to the east (right) side of its allocated space.

Third, all the geometry managers try to compact the widgets as much as possible unless you specifically tell it to do otherwise.  I told the grid manager to expand column 2 so that the extra space gets assigned to the cell that holds the Quit button.

Fourth, you need to tell the pack manager to expand the top widget so that it spans the entire window.  The directive for that is `fill="x"`.

Fifth, you have a redundant call to the pack manager at the end of your `createWidgets` function.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill="x")
        self.createWidgets()
        self.master.title("Log Parser")
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.Run_Main = tk.Button(self)
        self.Run_Main["text"] = "Browse.."
        # self.Run_Main["fg"] = "blue"
        self.Run_Main["command"] = self.Sayhello
        self.Label = tk.Label(self)
        self.Label["text"] = 'Processing...'
        self.progressbar = Progressbar(mode="indeterminate", maximum=20)
        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "Quit!"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit
        self.Label.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.Run_Main.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.QUIT.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e")
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    def Sayhello(self):
       print("Hello")

# scroll text inside application frame
class scrollTxtArea:
    def __init__(self, root):
        frame = tk.Frame(root)
        frame.pack()
        self.textPad(frame)
        return

    def textPad(self, frame):
        # add a frame and put a text area into it
        textPad = tk.Frame(frame)
        self.text = tk.Text(textPad, height=18, width=60)
        self.text.config()
        # add a vertical scroll bar to the text area
        scroll = tk.Scrollbar(textPad)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set,background="black", foreground="green")
        # pack everything
        self.text.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=2)
        scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        textPad.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        return

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.option_add('*font', ('verdana', 9, 'bold'))
app = Application(master=root)
scrollFrame = scrollTxtArea(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Really elaborate and helpful answer. Thanks

Comment: _"The pack geometry manager, as the name implies, packs the widgets as close together as possible."_ - that is a somewhat misleading statement. You can use `pack` and still have items far apart.

Comment: @BryanOakley You're absolutely right - I find the grid geometry manager easier to use in these situations but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

These [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/LayoutsideTOPLEFT.htm), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089942/difference-between-fill-and-expand-options-for-tkinter-pack-method) helped. The other option would be to use tkinter's [grid manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), it will be more intuitive and keep you more organized in the future.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.master.title("Log Parser")
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.Run_Main = tk.Button(self)
        self.Run_Main["text"] = "Browse.."
        # self.Run_Main["fg"] = "blue"
        self.Run_Main["command"] = self.Sayhello
        self.Run_Main.pack(side='left')
        self.Label = tk.Label(self)
        self.Label["text"] = 'Processing...'
        self.Label.pack(side='left')
        self.progressbar = Progressbar(mode="indeterminate", maximum=20)
        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "Quit!"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit
        self.QUIT.pack(side='right')
        self.pack(side="top", fill=tk.BOTH) # changes here

    def Sayhello(self):
       print("Hello")

# scroll text inside application frame
class scrollTxtArea:
    def __init__(self, root):
        frame = tk.Frame(root)
        frame.pack()
        self.textPad(frame)
        return

    def textPad(self, frame):
        # add a frame and put a text area into it
        textPad = tk.Frame(frame)
        self.text = tk.Text(textPad, height=18, width=60)
        self.text.config()
        # add a vertical scroll bar to the text area
        scroll = tk.Scrollbar(textPad)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set,background="black", foreground="green")
        # pack everything
        self.text.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=2)
        scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        textPad.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        return

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.option_add('*font', ('verdana', 9, 'bold'))
app = Application(master=root)
scrollFrame = scrollTxtArea(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple fixes you can make in order to get the behavior you want.

First, you need to pack `Application` so that it fills the window:

```
class Application(...):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.pack(fill="x")
```

Next, simply pack the quick button on the right side of the window:

```
self.QUIT.pack(side="right", anchor='e')
```

---

Even though the above is all you need to do in this specific example, there are additional things you can do to make your job much easier.

I would recommend creating a frame specifically for the buttons. You can pack it at the top. Then, put the buttons inside this frame, and pack them either on the left or right. You'll get the same results, but you'll find it easier to add additional buttons later.

I also find that it makes the code much easier to read, write, maintain, and visualize when you separate widget creation from widget layout.

```
class Application(...):
    ...
    def createWidgets(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(self)
        toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.Run_Main = tk.Button(toolbar)
        self.Label = tk.Label(toolbar)
        self.QUIT = tk.Button(toolbar)
        ...
        self.Run_Main.pack(side="left")
        self.Label.pack(side="left", fill="x")
        self.QUIT.pack(side="right")
        ...
```