# PYTHON: How to anchor two labels to top using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("window")

yellow_header = tk.Label(root, text = 'Header', bg = 'light yellow')
yellow_header.pack(side = tk.TOP, anchor = tk.N, expand = 1, fill = tk.X)

yellow_header2 = tk.Label(root, text = 'paragraph', bg = 'light yellow')
yellow_header2.pack(side = tk.TOP, anchor = tk.N, expand = 1, fill = tk.X)

root.mainloop()
```

For the above code I am trying to have both these labels anchored to the top and directly below one another.  Although the first label (yellow_header) anchors to the top, where as the second label (yellow_header2) when expanded move towards the centre.  How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `expand=1`. From [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112024617/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm):

> The **expand** option tells the manager to assign additional space to the widget box. If the parent widget is made larger than necessary to hold all packed widgets, any exceeding space will be distributed among all widgets that have the **expand** option set to a non-zero value.

With `expand=1`, when you make the window larger, the space is distributed between the two labels. So even though you only tell them to fill it in the X direction, they are given the space in both directions. The second label is placed directly under the space that is available to the first label, which is half of the window.

I've tried to explain and visualize the difference between `expand` and `fill` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090362/3714930).

P.S. You don't need `anchor=tk.N` either. When the space available to the widget and the size of the widget are the same, the anchor option makes no difference. Also, `side=tk.TOP` is the default so you could decide to omit that too, leaving you with only `fill=tk.X`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs I see:

> The Text widget is used to display text in multiple lines.

and this seems to work:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("window")

yellow_header = tk.Label(root, text = 'Header\nParagraph', bg = 'light yellow')
yellow_header.pack(side = tk.TOP, anchor = tk.N, expand = 1, fill = tk.X)
```

That might be a bit OS specific and perhaps the proper way would be:

```
import os
...
yellow_header = tk.Label(root, text = 'Header' + os.linesep + 'Paragraph', bg = 'light yellow')
```

When increasing the length of the first string the second still remains in the center.