# How to change the place of the GIF in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, gif

I have a this code where GIF file shows in tkinter canvas. The problem is that I need it to be in the top right corner, not in the middle. I tried and searched a lot but there's nothing in the internet about GIF placement in tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

wd = tk.Tk()
wd.geometry("1000x600")

frameCnt = 54
frames = [PhotoImage(file='teamfortress2.gif', format='gif -index %i' % (i))
          for i in range(frameCnt)]

def update(ind):
    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind == frameCnt:
        ind = 0
    label.configure(image=frame)
    wd.after(100, update, ind)


label = Label(wd)
label.pack()
wd.after(0, update, 0)

wd.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter has class `tk.Canvas` but you show `tk.Label` with image in window - so `"showing in tkinter canvas"` can be misleading.

Comment: @furas: Good eye — and something I missed concentrating only on their code…

Comment: Chris-Robin: Please add a link to your .gif file to your question — or else it's difficult for others to run your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you're really asking about is how to put the `Label` with the GIF on it in the top right corner. Fortunately the tkinter `pack()` geometry manager has an option for that named `anchor=`<sup>✶</sup> which determines where the widget is placed inside the packing box. It uses compass terminology, so the top right would be the North East corner (or NE).

<sup>✶</sup> See [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111222645id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)

```
...
label = Label(wd)
label.pack(anchor=tk.NE)  # <- Puts label in top-right corner.
wd.after(0, update, 0)

wd.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`anchor` option in `Label()` set the place where your text is inside the `label` widget.

`fill` option in `pack()` set the size of your widget, an nice example is in [fhdrsdg'post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090362/13771162)

Then try this :

```py
label = Label(wd, anchor="ne")  # "ne" for North-East
label.pack(fill="x")
```

Comment: The `Label`'s `anchor` option controls how text is positioned within *it*, **not** how the widget itself is positioned in its own container (`wd` which is the root window in the OP's code).

Comment: Yes anchor affect text position inside the `label` widget. And `fill="x"` option allow the `label`'s widget's container to fill the x axis. I think that is what I have written, but it might be not clear.

Comment: Your approach seem like a somewhat roundabout way of doing things, plus making the `Label` widget fill the entire horizontal space of its container — besides being unnecessary — seems like a potentially undesirable side-effect.