# How do I position my tkinter widgets right?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a simple tkinter app and I want to make the layout look better.

The layout currently looks like this:
[Simple Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpTYI.png)
But I want it to look like this:
[Wanted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDrM7.png)

The code for it is right here:

```
self.max_length = Entry(self);
self.max_length.pack(side = LEFT);

self.load_button = Button(self, text = "Load Story", command = self.generate_story);
self.load_button.pack(side = LEFT);

self.script_template = Text(self);
self.script_template.pack(side = TOP);
```

Any way to make the layout like what I want?

Comment: You want the button to be aligned to the right of the entry widget and that’s what you’ve achieved, isn’t it?

Comment: I want the Text widget to be below the Entry and Button widget.

Comment: Try putting the entry and button in a frame that is packed using `side=TOP` and then pack the text widget with `side=BOTTOM`. Or you can use `grid` instead of `pack`.

Comment: I don't have exact code you'll need in my head, but I do know that you should be using `grid` instead of `pack` to achieve what you're after.

Comment: The text widget isn’t visible in the image. I’d suggest that you fill some text in the Text widget so that we can see how it’s positioned

Comment: @BenjaminJamesDrury You can still use pack in this case but you will probably need to add a frame for the entry and button.

Comment: I'll try it, so make your things answers and I'll chose one that works.

Comment: @Dinux the Text widget is on the left of the Button and Entry widgets.

Comment: @TheLizzard got it right.

Comment: @BenjaminEcker did you really mean to accept the non-answer below? Or was this a mistake while trying to downvote?

Comment: Opps! Thanks for telling me!

Comment: It won't let me downvote.

Comment: @BenjaminEcker no worries, note that the previously accepted answer is now no longer accepted ;)

Comment: There has been some very suspicious voting going on with regards to this and other recent questions. While none of us can tell for sure what the cause is, I have notified the moderators and have asked them to investigate it, and hopefully they can sort things out.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure, since us regular users can only report suspicions, but again, the moderators have the tools to check for strange voting patterns and to ban accounts if any are found. If you have done nothing wrong, then you have absolutely nothing to worry about.

Comment: Good, then thank you.

Comment: I see that some of my suspicions were in fact correct, and at least one account, "Charles Darwin", has been expunged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
top_frame.pack(side="top")

max_length = tk.Entry(top_frame)
max_length.pack(side="left")

load_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text="Load Story")
load_button.pack(side="right")

script_template = tk.Text(root)
script_template.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

An answer that uses a frame to hold the entry and button. To make the widgets expand, you can use `pack`'s `fill`/`expand` parameters. For more info on `expand` vs `fill`, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28089942/11106801).

With this answer the main window has only 2 widgets (the frame and the text widget). Inside the frame widget there are 2 more widgets (the entry and button).

This can also be done by replacing `pack` with `grid` but will leave someone else to write that answer.

Comment: After a bit of tinkering I made it work, thanks!

Comment: Man, stackoverflow won't let me mark your thing as an answer!

Comment: @BenjaminEcker Np, don't worry. After a few hours look back at the question as someone will probably give an answer with `.grid` which might be more useful for future problems.